# How to query collections within MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

In my database I have a collection called "users" that holds user information. I would like to add a search function that allows users to search others by username.

My database is correctly connected in my app.js:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mobiusapp');
var db = mongoose.connection;
```

I would like to access the "user" collection of my database to find the searched users. Here is the code I currently have to do this:

```
app.post('/users/search', function(req, res, next){

  var result = db.users.findOne();

  console.log(result);
});
```

However, when I run this, I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined`.

Is there some way to connect the collection I would like to access so that I can use it? Everything I try always ends with this error. Please help because I have no idea how to fix this. Thank you!

Comment: You have some examples here https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/query/

Comment: Thank you so much Veeram! This worked perfectly for me. I really really appreciate it.